# Electron.Net: How can i start a window in maximized mode?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, electron, electron.net

I'm using electron.Net, but when I start the main window, It always opens small size aligned to the center.

This is my code:

```js
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    } else {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    Task.Run(async () => await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync());

    Electron.Menu.SetApplicationMenu(new MenuItem[] {});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based the `BrowserWindow` [source](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/blob/master/ElectronNET.API/BrowserWindow.cs) and the [Electron.NET Demo](https://github.com/ElectronNET/electron.net-api-demos/blob/master/ElectronNET-API-Demos/Startup.cs), the following one opens the Electron Window in the Maximized Window.

This just calls the `BrowserWindow`'s `Maximize()` event manually just after showing the Window, when everything ready.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    } else {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
    
    if (HybridSupport.IsElectronActive)
    {
        ElectronBootstrap();
    }
}

public async void ElectronBootstrap()
{
    var browserWindow = await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync(new BrowserWindowOptions
    {
        Width = 1152,
        Height = 940,
        Show = false
    });

    await browserWindow.WebContents.Session.ClearCacheAsync();

    // For the gracefull showing of the Electron Window when ready
    browserWindow.OnReadyToShow += () =>
    {
        browserWindow.Show();
        browserWindow.Maximize();
    }
    Electron.Menu.SetApplicationMenu(new MenuItem[] {});
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much my friend, that's exactly what i needed.

Comment: Welcome @JesusSerratoAguilar If this works, mark as the answer to help others.